# C++ how to turn all `\` into `/` inside of string?

Tags: c++, string, replace

So I try `std::replace(diff_path.begin(), diff_path.end(), "\\", "/");` but it seems not to compile on my visual studio. What to do - how to turn all `\` into `/` inside of string?

```
Error   3   error C2446: '==' : no conversion from 'const char *' to 'int'  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\algorithm    1311    1   CloudServerPrototype

Error   5   error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'const char [2]' to 'char'   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\algorithm    1312    1   CloudServerPrototype    

Error   4   error C2040: '==' : 'int' differs in levels of indirection from 'const char [2]'    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\algorithm    1311    1   CloudServerPrototype
```

Comment: It _seems_ not to compile, or really doesn't compile in which case you should get an error message...which would be...what?

Comment: "seems"? Either it does, or it doesn't, and if it doesn't, it will tell you exactly why.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use character literals, not string literals:

```
std::replace(diff_path.begin(), diff_path.end(), '\\', '/');
                                                 ^~~~  ^~~
```

The `value_type` of a `std::string` is `char` (each element in a string is a single character).

Answer (score 4):

You did it right in your question title.  Fix:

```
 std::replace(diff_path.begin(), diff_path.end(), '\\', '/');
```

Elements of an std::string are characters, not strings.